# How to convert XML to Change Set

Tags: salesforcedx, change-set, xml

I usually get XML package to Deploy via ANT but sometimes ANT doesn't work appropriately. In emergencies, I don't get time to fix the issue. So i wonder if I could get a way to convert XML to Change Set. I have configured my build.xml like below; when i run this command components get deployed but doesn't create change set. I have used Full Name tag in XML package but still no positive results

```
<target name="populatechangesetsandboxmine">
<sf:deploy username="${sf.atestdev.username}" password="${sf.atestdev.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}"
serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="C:\Users\learner\Desktop\Destruction\src" rollbackOnError="true" autoUpdatePackage="true" singlePackage="true"/>
</target>
```

I also tried creating a empty change set in my target org and getting the change set updated but it throws an error of the change set already existing in the org.
Please advise. I'd appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changesets are only made available through Salesforce's Web UI, so the quick answer to your question is "no". I see that you have this question tagged as salesforcedx as well. Do you have the Salesforce CLI installed? It'd also help if you went into more detail about what "but sometimes ANT doesn't work appropriately" means.

Comment: You can't create a changeset through ANT but you can update it. So it should work when you created an empty changeset. Can you please post your package.xml and error screenshot. Please edit and update the question instead of posting in the comments.